# Java удобная библиотека для логгирования в файлы

Tags: java, логирование

Ищу библиотеки на джаве для логгирования, которая подойдет мне по таким требованиям:

- логирование в файл
- при рестарте сервиса логгирование ведется в новый файл
- можно задавать формат имен файлов: например, на основе текущей даты
- простая конфигурация без необходимости передавать программе путь к xml-конфигу

Что мне может подойти? Сервисы рестартятся по крону, поэтому чем меньше параметров программа получает через командную строку, тем лучше.

Comment: Тоже интересно. Логированием никогда не занимался.

Answer (score 1):

Промышленным стандартом логгирования является [Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) - в принципе позволяет делать все что вы описали в своем вопросе.

С недавних пор является модным фасад логгирования [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/index.html), который позволяет абстрагироваться от реального логгера и может скрывать под собой более-менее любой логгер, включая встроенный [Java Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) или тот же самый Log4J

В общем - решайте сами, но знание Log4J - это как бы must have в багаже нормального Java девелопера.

Comment: Зачем "навязывать" людям неправильный стереотип про "must have"? Я о том, что на каждую "фенечку" нужно обязательно прикрутить внешнюю либу к проекту. Стандартного средства логирования вполне хватает. Не стоит в каждом видеть корпоративного девелопера.

Comment: Замечательно что вы добавили свой комментарий, люди прочитают его и сами для себя решат: *must have* или *нуегонафиг* :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `LoggerManager`.
Пример:

```
final String folder = "log",
             logger = "./log.logger";
final File log = new File(".", folder);
log.mkdir();
try (final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(logger))) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Где `log.logger` файл из корня ну может быть где угодно, где захотите, с настройками:

**log.logger**:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler,\
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,\
com.logs.LogHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = log/java%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = com.MyLogger
```

Так-же, можно указать лимиты, количества, уровни, фильтры, добавки ну и т. д.

**handlers** (указываются классы через запятую, в качестве обработчиков корневого регистратора):

Пример такого обработчика простой:

```
public class LogHandler extends FileHandler {
    public LogHandler() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super();
    }
}
```

Мы также можем использовать новое свойство для `my.handlers` и это будут новые обработчики.

`com.MyLogger`- который указан в свойствах `*.FileHandler.formatter` класс из пакета `com` (может быть где угодно, где захотите):

```
class MyLogger extends Formatter {

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return record.getLevel().getName() +" --- " +  record.getMessage();
    }
}
```

По этому шаблону будет писать в файл, то, что укажем.

Все это можно узнать в [LoggerManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html)